# How to pass arguments for sftp.get in python

Tags: python, parameter-passing, paramiko, pysftp

```
a = raw_input("Select your project: ")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cd test \n cd software \n cd {0} \n ls'.format(a))
softwares = stdout.readlines()
```

I got output for this. But, when I am trying to get output for the below lines of code,

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cd test \n cd software \n cd {0} \n pwd'.format(a))
pwd = stdout.readlines()
pwd1 = '\n'.join(pwd)
print pwd1

b = raw_input("Select the software you want to download: ")

sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.get('{1}/{2}'.format(pwd1,b),'{2}'.format(b))
```

I am hitting with the below error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\Python scripts for
>   writing testcase\Paramiko.py", line 32, in 
>       sftp.get('{1}/{2}'.format(pwd1,b),'{2}'.format(b)) IndexError: tuple index out of range

How I need to pass the arguments there, as the path will be changed for different selections.

Answer (score 2):

number in the format string should starts from 0, not from 1.

```
>>> '{1}'.format(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
>>> '{0}'.format(1)
'1'
>>> '{}'.format(1)  # auto numbering
'1'
```

See [Format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).

If you're using python 2.7+, you can omit the number completely. (auto numbering). And the second format can be just `b` (no need to use format at all, because `b` is already a string object)

```
sftp.get('{}/{}'.format(pwd1, b), b)
```

Answer (score 0):

> '{2}'.format(b)

You tell format to insert the second argument, yet only provide one. Change to {1}.